# not able to login to ec2 instance as I changed the chown of ubuntu to another user

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04

I was adding another user to my ubuntu 14.04 ec2 instance and I added another user but by mistake I changed the chown for ubuntu user also and now I cannot ssh into my ec2 instance..

The command  ran is pasted below and I am pretty confident that this is what screwed up everything as I saw the ownership of ubuntu also changing

```
sudo chown -R dhaval:dhaval /home/dhaval/.
```

Is there anything that I can do to be able to ssh again.

Any help on this will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You could probably:

- Stop that instance
- Detach the boot disk ("Disk A")
- Attach Disk A to another instance and mount it
- `chown` the directory back to the correct setting
- Detach Disk A
- Reattach Disk A to the original instance (with the same device identifier, eg `/dev/sda1`)
- Start the instance

Comment: Thanks for your advise John..I would try this and inform you..it looks complicated to me but I will try it

Comment: Just think of it like pulling a USB disk off one computer and plugging it into another to make some changes. (Just in concept, not in reality!)